# Ошибка при установке Python: Microsoft.VC90.CRT

Tags: python, windows-10, python-2.7

Ошибка во время установки:

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT, version="9.0.30729.1", publicKeyTocken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b", processorArchitecture="amd64", type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information.

Недавно переустановился на 10-у, на 8.1 такой проблемы не было.

Comment: похоже на ошибку инсталлятора Windows, попробуйте разные дистрибутивы Python поустанавливать

Comment: Можно пожалуйста подробней, какие дистрибутивы например установить. Я новичок и никаких таких не знаю

Comment: альтернативный дистрибутив от компании ActiveState, Anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался простым. В инсталляторе нужно было выбрать "Только для меня", а не "Для всех пользователей".